# Scapy and rdpcap function

Tags: python, networking, pcap, packet-capture, scapy

I'm using `rdpcap` function of Scapy to read a PCAP file.
I also use the module described in a [link to HTTP support in Scapy](http://blog.sbarbeau.fr/2011/06/http-support-in-scapy.html) which is needed in my case, as I have to retrieve all the HTTP requests and responses and their related packets.

I noticed that parsing a large PCAP file the `rdpcap` function takes too much time to read it.

Is there a solution to read a `pcap` file faster?

Comment: How big is your pcap file? How long does it take to read it? Is it really too long (even for loading it only once)? How many times do you want to read it (rhetorical question)?

Comment: My file is greater than 300 MB, I have to launch the Python script more than once.

Comment: @auino, what specifically is the problem with the read time?  Is it that it takes too long to develop your script when you're parsing a 300MB file every time you make a change, or is there some real-time processing requirement?  Also, please give us a sense for what is an acceptable parse time

Comment: It takes about 1 hours... it's not good, as I have to parse the data just loaded...

Comment: Please use upvote to thank and do not thank in question.

Answer (score 11):

Scapy has another method `sniff` which you can use to read the pcap files too:

```
def method_filter_HTTP(pkt):
    #Your processing
      
sniff(offline="your_file.pcap", prn=method_filter_HTTP, store=0)
```

`rdpcap` loads the entire pcap file to the memory. Hence it uses a lot of memory and as you said its slow. While `sniff` reads one packet at a time and passes it to the provided `prn` function. That `store=0` parameter ensures that the packet is deleted from memory as soon as it is processed.

Answer (score 4):

While I agree the load time is longer than one might expect, it is likely because the file is being parsed to generate an array of highly composed objects. What I've had to do was use `editcap` to chop up the packet captures to make reading them a bit easier. For example:

```
$ editcap -B 2013-05-2810:05:55 -i 5 -F libpcap inputcapture.pcap outputcapture.pcap
```

Please note: a full explanation of the switches of this command is available [here](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/AppToolseditcap.html).

Also, the `-F libpcap` part seemed to be necessary (at least for me) to get scapy's `pcap` function able to parse the file. (This is supposed to be the default pcap file output format, but this was not the case for me, for whatever reason. You can verify the file type of your input and output files with `capinfos` (e.g., simply enter `capinfos your_capture.pcap`).

Both `capinfos` and `editcap` are available with the WireShark distribution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a more responsive code, consider using `PcapReader()` instead of `rdpcap()`.

`PcapReader()` creates a generator and loads a packet only when it is needed, as opposed to `rdpcap()` which loads the entire trace into memory. `PcapReader()` is, therefore, well-suited for a large trace that takes forever to load with `rdpcap()`, or throws a `MemoryError` because it's simply too large for your system.

Example code:

```
packets = PcapReader('filename.pcap')
for packet in packets:
    mac_src = packet[Ether].src
    mac_dst = packet[Ether].dst
    ...
```

Please refer to the `PcapReader()` [documentation](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.utils.html#scapy.utils.PcapReader) for more information.

If you are only concerned about how long it takes to get the final output, then `rdpcap()` might have an advantage over `PcapReader()`, although I'm not sure about the magnitude of difference.

Answer (score 1):

Since Scapy 2.4.3 it has built-in support to [parse HTTP](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layers/http.html) sessions. It can be used with the `sniff()` [sessions](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#advanced-sniffing-sniffing-sessions) functionality. e.g.

```
pkts = sniff(offline="http_chunk.pcap.gz", session=TCPSession, store=0)
```

When using the `TCPsession` functionality with an HTTP/1 capture it returns a list of 'packets' which contain the assembled data from all underlying packets that make up each HTTPRequest, HTTPResponse. It will still also return individual packets such as Ack packets. So, for example, checking if a 'packet' `haslayer(HTTPResponse)` then that 'packet' contains the entire response payload. It's also possible to use the [`answers()`](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.layers.http.html?highlight=answers#scapy.layers.http.HTTPResponse.answers) functionality to match requests and responses. Note you can use `sniff()` for a live capture, or with `offline` packet capture, or a list of packets.