# Scapy sniff filter not functioning

Tags: python, networking, scapy

I am having trouble applying a filter to the sniff command in Scapy. In the simplest case, I can sniff 10 packets in the Scapy cli, like this:

```
Welcome to Scapy (2.3.3)
>>> pkts = sniff(count=10)
>>> for p in pkts: p.summary()
... 
'IP / TCP xx.xx.xx.xx:ssh > xx.xx.xx.xx:53128 PA / Raw'
'IP / TCP xx.xx.xx.xx:60661 > xx.xx.xx.xx:http_alt PA / Raw'
'IP / TCP xx.xx.xx.xx:http_alt > xx.xx.xx.xx:60661 A'
'IP / TCP xx.xx.xx.xx:32874 > xx.xx.xx.xx:http S'
'IP / TCP xx.xx.xx.xx:https > xx.xx.xx.xx:58026 PA / Raw'
'IP / TCP xx.xx.xx.xx:58026 > xx.xx.xx.xx:https A'
'IP / TCP xx.xx.xx.xx:60804 > xx.xx.xx.xx:http_alt A'
'IP / TCP xx.xx.xx.xx:63244 > xx.xx.xx.xx:http_alt PA / Raw'
'IP / TCP xx.xx.xx.xx:http_alt > xx.xx.xx.xx:63244 A'
'IP / TCP xx.xx.xx.xx:43843 > xx.xx.xx.xx:http_alt A'
```

but when I try:

```
pkts = sniff(count=10, filter='tcp')
```

It never finishes, just waits for packets.

I'm on a rented VPS running Ubuntu 16.04 server and I know there some limited capabilities around networking. For instance, I'm not able to use linux traffic control (tc).

Any ideas on how this could be the case?

**edit:**
BPF filters do function correctly for tcpdump.

Comment: FYI: my workaround is to create a pcap file using the filtered tcpdump and then read that file into python/scapy.

Comment: also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37964206/9141316) for sniffing form large pcap files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because the BPF filter is not compiled for the correct interface. You should get the current development version of Scapy (from https://github.com/secdev/scapy) and specify the interface in your `sniff()` call:

```
pkts = sniff(count=10, filter='tcp', iface='eth0')  # replace eth0 with your interface name
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre. If I'm reading Github correctly, 2.3.3 is the current release. But adding the iface doesn't resolve the issue. I get the same behavior

Comment: 2.3.3 is the current release, but the current development version includes a lot of fixes that might help you. That's why I said "you should get the current development version of Scapy".

Comment: you're right. switching to dev branch fixes all sorts of things